# How to get for each product in category archive page unique div set up and classes in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to make custom category archive pages in woocommerce with separate divs and classes for each product?

In woocommerce file content-product.php i have the following code:

```
global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-one-third">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        /**
     *
     * close link
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_close_link' );
    ?>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked add to cart
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
        /**
     *
     * close link
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_close_link' );
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I copied this code and changed the classes it just displays each product twice.

I've spent lots of time could not find the answer anywhere.

What I want exactly to be able to get that outcome:

```
<!-- First product -->
<div class="columns">
<div class="column custom-class-1">
Here first product codes
</div>
<div class="custom-class-something">
Custom codes
</div>
</div>

<!-- Second product -->
<div class="columns">
<div class="custom-class-something-else">
Custom codes
</div>
<div class="column custom-class-2">
Here second product codes
</div>
</div>
```

And so on for I plan 6 or 7 products that could be looped to make it 12/14 products on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the soulution and described it in another question here:
[Create couple of unique classes repeating in a loop Woocommerce shop loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800540/create-couple-of-unique-classes-repeating-in-a-loop-woocommerce-shop-loop/55818498#55818498)

Answer (score 1):

I edit your code for set unique class for every product. I get product id and create custom class name with it, if your product id is **149**, the class name for each product column became `product-149`:

```
global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}

$first_custom_class = 'product-' . $product->get_id();
$second_custom_class = 'custom-code-' . $product->get_id();

?>
<div <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-one-third <?php echo esc_attr($first_custom_class); ?>">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        /**
     *
     * close link
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_close_link' );
    ?>
        </div>

        <div class="column <?php echo esc_attr($second_custom_class); ?>">

            <!-- YOUR CUSTOM CODES-->

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Outcome:

```
<!-- First product with id 149-->
<div class="columns">

    <div class="column product-149">
    Here first product codes
    </div>

    <div class="custom-code-149">
    Custom codes
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Second product with id 150-->
<div class="columns">

    <div class="column product-150">
    Here second product codes
    </div>

    <div class="custom-code-150">
    Custom codes
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is close to what I want but I see I did not ask a proper question. I want actually a loop with six or seven classes that are going to be repeated in a loop. Also if possible custom code class column want it to be after the product column, in next colmuns div I want it to switch places, and custom code column to be before the product column. And to switch that for every other columns div.